# Old analog oscilloscope (Advance - Gould OS 240) front panel output

Tags: oscilloscope

I can't find the exact manual for this pretty simple old oscilloscope (pretty good functionally) - I've found some pretty similar ones, for other models - so I have a couple of questions regarding  the front panel.

There is a small pin labeled Gate o/p. Is this something like a probe callibration output? 
Next to it there is a "banana plug" socket input for external trigger (obvious) and ground. What is this ground used for (since there is a mains  ground similar socket at the back panel)?

[image: Here's a photo]

Thanks in advance

PS. I found this info here https://www.electronicdesign.com/displays/cross-trigger-two-oscilloscopes-create-delayed-sweep-display                                                                     Does it give any help or clue?  Apparently it's a signal. It's a binding post that supplies a positive pulse for the duration of the timebase (according to the similar osc. tektronix's manual). Any idea how it can be used?

Comment: Where's the photo?

Comment: Proper grounding and managing signals is so important in some measurements that grounding is provided at the interface.  In modern oscilloscopes the grounding is designed into the connector.  I have no idea what "Gate o/p" is for.

Comment: It may also be the output of the trigger circuit of the scope - in that case it may be difficult to make any sense of it measuring it with the scope itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question... after finding, purchasing and reading the manual. ...According to the manufacturer: "This output provides a positive going sq. wave of approximately 20V amplitude from a source impedance of 15kOhm. Its freq. is dependant on the setting of time/div and is suitable for probe compensation.
If anyone ever cares or needs the manual I can send the pdf.
Thanks

Comment: That seems as though they're offering that instead of the typical 1 kHz, 1 V, squarewave signal output found on most scopes of that era. You'd use it to adjust the 10:1 probe trimmer capacitor, turning it until the resultant waveform has nice square corners.

Comment: unfortunatelly is disconnected and in order to connect it, it need a full disassembly of the boards...so i just use an external generator for compensation

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work out the Gate o/p function for yourself by checking it with the scope itself, and fiddling with the controls. It is probably the timebase output.

Answer (score 0):

The gate output is the Z axis blanking =0 during which the horizontal sweep HV returns in a finite interval for use with synchronizing external signals when needed.

Otherwise the sweep frequency is frequency locked to the input recurring trigger frequency and starts when the trigger condition occurs for either Auto mode or Manual trigger select.

I have used this rarely, but in combination with fancy measurement techniques may be useful. Don’t worry about it until you need it.